# Compiling Erlang code on Windows

Tags: windows, erlang, installation, compilation

I installed Erlang 13B and tried to follow the tutorials.

Every time I get to `c(tut)`, I get an error instead of `(ok, tut)`, so it seems like there are no modules installed. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I've tried Emacs but I don't really know how to use it and haven't even got close to getting the Erlang mode working. For instance, where do I type:

```
  (setq load-path (cons  "C:/Program Files/erl5.6.2/lib/tools-<ToolsVer>/emacs"
    load-path))
  (setq erlang-root-dir "C:/Program Files/erl5.6.2")
  (setq exec-path (cons "C:/Program Files/erl5.6.2/bin" exec-path))
  (require 'erlang-start)
```

Comment: I you are discovering both Erlang and Emacs at the same time (which are both amazing great pieces of software) I suggest you put Emacs on the side as a start. Dont learn two systemz at the same time. You can use any text editor with Erlang, and Notepad++ is doing a great job too.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For `c(tut)` to work, there has to be a `tut.erl` file in the current directory.

This is easy to accomplish if you start the Erlang interpreter from the command line, as is common on systems like Linux and OS X, but this isn't the usual pattern on Windows.  When you start Erlang on Windows from the icon in the Start menu, the current working directory defaults to the location of `werl.exe`, which isn't where your `tut.erl` file is.

To make your command work as expected, you have to change your working directory to be the location of `tut.erl` after starting the Erlang shell. If `tut.erl` is on the Desktop, the command will be something like this on Vista or Windows 7:

```
cd("c:/Users/myname/Desktop").
```

(Yes, you have to use forward slashes.  Backslashes are special in Erlang strings.)

On Windows XP and older, your Desktop folder is buried much deeper.  It might be simpler to put `werl.exe` in the system `PATH` and use the command line on such systems.

It isn't necessary, but you might want to consider installing [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/). Its Bash shell will give you a more Linux or OS X like environment, which will help you work with other tutorials that are structured for those OSes.

Comment: By the way, once you have a *.beam file in the directory with other Erlang code, you can set up a Windows file association between *.beam files and werl.exe, so that when you double-click them, Erlang loads them up and implicitly ends up setting its working directory to the location of the file.

Answer (score 10):

After you install Erlang open the shell and do:

```
1> pwd().
C:/Program Files/erl5.7.1/usr
ok
2>
```

Assume you have a file; "tut.erl" on your desktop. Content might look like this:

```
-module(tut).
-compile(export_all).

hello_world() ->
  hello.
```

You must change the path of the current working directory to the desktop first (or where ever you want to do the compile). Like this perhaps:

```
2> cd("F:/Desktop").
F:/Desktop
ok
3>
```

Then you can perform the compile.

```
3> c(tut).
{ok,tut}
4>
```

Then test the module

```
4> tut:hello_world().
hello
5>
```

More info refer to the documentation here: [Erlang official documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/man/shell.html)
More info on the shell, look here: [Shell module](http://erlang.org/doc/man/shell.html)

Hope this gets your started.

Comment: Oh and by the way, in windows the absolutely best tip I have is to create a windows shortcut to werl.exe for each project you have and then change the "Run in" property to the current working directory. Another tip is to add flags in the "Target" property such as -sname, -setcookie (useful in distributed environments) and perhaps -pa to add additional paths to your code search paths. more info about those here: http://erlang.org/doc/man/erl.html

Comment: Thanks for taking time out to answer my question but I can't get the c(tut) to work, I still get this:

Erlang (BEAM) emulator version 5.6.2 [smp:2] [async-threads:0]

Eshell V5.6.2  (abort with ^G)
1> cd("F:/Desktop").
C:/Program Files/erl5.6.2/usr
ok
2> c(tut).
./tut.erl:none: no such file or directory
error
3> 

Since all the tutorials seem to assume that these modules are already installed I thought they came as standard; I can't seem to track own any modules, which is a bit of a downer.

Comment: Your command cd("F:/Desktop"). is hitting the windows command line problem that cd cannot change directories across drive letters.  Modify your erlang shortcut to set working directory to F:
btw help(). shows shell commands.

Answer (score 1):

You can also create an initialization file named `.erlang` under `YourErlangInstallationPath\usr\`

the content of the file should look something like this;

```
io:format("consulting .erlang in ~p~n" ,
[element(2,file:get_cwd())]).
%% Edit to the directory where you store your code
c:cd("O:/Erlang.Umut").
io:format("Now in:~p~n" , [element(2,file:get_cwd())]).
```

it will automatically change the path to your working folder. (Obviously, my path is `O:/Erlang.Umut`, you need to replace it with yours.)

No need to change folders every time you launch console. Console will be able to reach your erl files directly.

Answer (score 1):

I recently tried Erlang on windows.

use the console window to make sure the text editor you are using is giving your files the correct extension  ie. filename.erl and not filename.erl.txt like mine was!

when I saved my files in notepad it added .txt so I saved in unicode. fixed

Answer (score 0):

If you are still getting "tut:erl:none: no such file or directory", the file name is wrong. If you open a Windows command prompt and move to your desktop and type "dir" you will see that tut.erl is really named tut.erl.txt. type "ren tut.erl.txt tut.erl" and now your compile will work.

Answer (score 0):

When werl's current working directory is same as the file to be compiled, the filename is given as an argument without the whole path.
Otherwise, for eg. Assuming tut.erl is placed at C:\ErLang tutorials, one may try compiling as,

```
c("C:\\ErLang tutorials\\tut").
```

Note:

1. Without double quotes the : causes syntax error
2. The backslash is given using escape sequence