# .erlang file in windows

Tags: erlang

I am reading Joe Armstrong's book on Erlang, "Programming Erlang: software for a concurrent world."

In a couple of places he talks about a .erlang file that lives where the erlang library lives, and it is supposed to let you change your environment.

I have tried it a few times, but nothing really seems to happen.

Is the name of the .erlang file different in windows?  Has it changed? Or am I just placing it in the wrong place?

I am putting the file here: C:\Program Files\erl5.7.2\bin

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278959/installing-erlang-on-windows-xp/1786966#1786966) it should be in `YourErlangInstallationPath\usr\` or `C:\Program Files\erl5.7.2\usr\` for you.